# How to add an entity to an existing entity MVC 2 EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am creating a MVC 2 website. I'm a beginner. I created a Model to use EF. The relationship is between a user table and a product table (one to many relationship). I am able to create new users and save them on the DB using linq to entities. My question is how do I add a product to an existing user. I was starting with the code below but it does not work. Intellisense doesn't see the queryuser.Product whats wrong with my code or what is the right way to do it. If someone can help me it would be great

```
 public void Insert(Product obj)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"] != null)
        {
            string userid2 = HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"].ToString();

            var queryuser = from p in entities.Users
                            where p.UserID == userid2
                            select p;

            queryuser.Product.Add(obj);
            entities.Users.Add(queryuser);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }                                                         
    }
```

I am calling this method from my controller.

Comment: Assuming `UserID` is a primary key, you want `var queryuser = entities.Users.Find(userid2)`

Comment: Its giving me the error: System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<tradeit.Models.User> does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension Method 'Find'...

Comment: post where you define `entities`

Comment: private TradeDBEntities1 entities = new TradeDBEntities1();

Comment: I Dont understand why it doesn work. I tried this : var firstuser = entities.Users.First();
firstuser.Products.Add(obj);  entities.SaveChanges(); and it worked but this is not what I want. Any ideas

Comment: I use @antlersoft answer I just modified it a bit. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryuser` is an IQueryable and you are treating it like a single object.

You might try replacing:

```
queryuser.Product.Add(obj);
entities.Users.Add(queryuser);
```

with

```
user = queryuser.First();
user.Product.Add(obj);
entities.Users.Add(user);
```

Comment: Its giving me an error: System.Linq.IQueryable<TradeIt.Models.User> does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'...

Comment: @omachu23 - yes, I forgot it's returning an IQueryable and not an IEnumerable-- I'm updating the answer

Comment: I Dont understand why it doesn work. I tried this : var firstuser = entities.Users.First();
firstuser.Products.Add(obj);  entities.SaveChanges(); and it worked but this is not what I want. Any ideas

Comment: I used your answer i just eliminated the last line and use entities.SaveChanges(); It works and I hope is the right thing to do. Thanks for the Help